# How to include nested effects in mixed effect model with lme4 package

Tags: r, static, lme4, mixed-models, random-effects

I am studying mixed models and have a doubt about nested random effects..

In the example, we tested subjects variable X and outcome Y and want to see if X is correlated with Y. The data were collected on 8 different mountains in 3 different site (i.e. mountain A was collected on site 1 2 and 3, mountain B site 1 2 and 3, etc). Site 1 of mountain A is not related at all with site 1 of mountain B.
Then we want to analyse the relationship Y ~ X controlling for mountain and site.

Since that site and mountain are nested, we created a variable "sample" that is

```
sample <- factor(mountainRange:site)*
```

Now, here is my doubt. The course suggest to do the analysis as following

```
mixed.lmer2 <- lmer(Y~ X + (1|mountain) + (1|sample), data = data)
```

But I don't understand why we include `(1|mountain)`. I thought I don't need to include it as it is already included in the variable  `(1|sample)`
What I mean is that I would run the analysis as following:

```
mixed.lmer3 <- lmer(Y~ X + (1|sample), data = data)
```

Could anyone explain why am I wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Mountain range is only included in `sample` to create  a unique identifier for site within mountains. You still have two sources of variation which need to be accounted for; the mountains and the site. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228800/crossed-vs-nested-random-effects-how-do-they-differ-and-how-are-they-specified may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You simply embedded `mountain` and `site` within the same term `sample`, which makes it nested. Alternatively, you could have done

```
mixed.lmer2 <- lmer(Y~ X + (1|mountain/site), data = data)
```

OR

```
mixed.lmer2 <- lmer(Y~ X + (1|mountain) + (1|mountain:site), data = data)
```

to represent the same thing. Again, you just did it outside the model formula.

Do see https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/228800/238878 for a more thorough answer.